# CentOS6.7 vsftpd 530 Permissions Denied

Tags: centos, ftp, centos6, vsftpd

I'm running CentOS 6.7 and I'm trying to successfully establish an FTP connection using vsftpd.

```
Status:         Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status:         Initializing TLS...
Status:         Verifying certificate...
Status:         TLS connection established.
Command:    USER testuser
Response:   530 Permission denied.
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

I tried checking /var/logs/messages and /var/logs/xferlog but the log is empty.  I also checked the home directory permissions of the local user and made sure that the user was listed in the userlist and not in the denylist

config:

```
local_enable=YES
pasv_address=108.41.178.133
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=40010
pasv_promiscuous=YES
pasv_enable=YES 
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list

listen=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem

ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=YES

dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is SELinux enabled ? If so try this http://serverfault.com/questions/302186/how-do-i-add-a-new-user-to-vsftpd-and-let-root-access-the-ftp-server/302201#302201. If that doesn't help and SELinux is enabled show us any relevant messages from /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: @Iain SELinux is currently disabled.  Does it need to be enabled and set to passive?

Answer (score 1):

Some options to check:

Is it possible that the username you're specifying is in the /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers list and disallowed from logging in?  (usually when a login is rejected before the pasword prompt, that's a sign it's a disallowed user account)

Also, check to see if the user you're logging in with has permissions to access the default home directory on file in vipw